# Elastic Search 2.3.4 Stops allocating shards with no obvious reason

Tags: elasticsearch

I am attempting to upgrade our Elastic Search cluster from 1.6 to 2.3.4. The upgrade seems to work, and I can see shard allocation starting to happen within Kopf - but at some point the shard allocation appears to stop with many shards left unallocated, and no errors being reported in the logs. Typically I'm left with 1200 / 3800 shards unallocated.

We have a typical 3 node cluster and I am trialing this standalone on my local machine with all 3 nodes running on my local machine.

I have seen similar symptoms reported - see https://t37.net/how-to-fix-your-elasticsearch-cluster-stuck-in-initializing-shards-mode.html
. The solution here seemed to be to manually allocate the shards, which I've tried (and works) but I'm at a loss to explain the behaviour of elastic search here. I'd prefer not to go down this route, as I want my cluster to spin up automatically without intervention.

There is also https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/14494 which seems to be resolved with the latest ES version, so shouldn't be a problem.

There are no errors in log files - I have upped the root level logging to 'DEBUG' in order to see what I can. What I can see is lines like the below for each unallocated shard (this from the master node logs):

```
[2016-07-26 09:18:04,859][DEBUG][gateway                  ] [germany] [index][4] found 0 allocations of [index][4], node[null], [P], v[0], s[UNASSIGNED], unassigned_info[[reason=CLUSTER_RECOVERED], at[2016-07-26T08:05:04.447Z]], highest version: [-1]
[2016-07-26 09:18:04,859][DEBUG][gateway                  ] [germany] [index][4]: not allocating, number_of_allocated_shards_found [0]
```

Config file (with comments removed):

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch-jm-2.3.4
node.name: germany

script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
```

If I query the cluster health after reallocation has stopped - I get the response below:

```
http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty

cluster_name                     : elasticsearch-jm-2.3.4
status                           : red
timed_out                        : False
number_of_nodes                  : 3
number_of_data_nodes             : 3
active_primary_shards            : 1289
active_shards                    : 2578
relocating_shards                : 0
initializing_shards              : 0
unassigned_shards                : 1264
delayed_unassigned_shards        : 0
number_of_pending_tasks          : 0
number_of_in_flight_fetch        : 0
task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis : 0
active_shards_percent_as_number  : 67.10046850598647
```

Further querying for shards - filtered to one index with unallocated shards. As can be seen - shard 0 and 4 are unallocated whereas shard 1 2 and 3 have been allocated :

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards

cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20      3 p STARTED       106  92.4kb 127.0.0.1 germany     
cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20      3 r STARTED       106  92.4kb 127.0.0.1 switzerland 
cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20      4 p UNASSIGNED                                      
cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20      4 r UNASSIGNED                                      
cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20      2 r STARTED       120  74.5kb 127.0.0.1 cyprus      
cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20      2 p STARTED       120  74.5kb 127.0.0.1 germany     
cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20      1 r STARTED       120  73.8kb 127.0.0.1 cyprus      
cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20      1 p STARTED       120  73.8kb 127.0.0.1 germany     
cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20      0 p UNASSIGNED                                      
cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20      0 r UNASSIGNED
```

Manually rerouting an unassigned shard appears to work - (stripped back results set)

```
http://localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute 
POST:
{ 
    "dry_run": true, 
    "commands": [ 
        { 
            "allocate": { 
                "index": "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20", 
                "shard": 4, 
                "node": "switzerland" , 
                "allow_primary": true
             } 
        } 
    ] 
}

Response:
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "state" : {
        "version" : 722,
        "state_uuid" : "Vw2vPoCMQk2ZosjzviD4TQ",
        "master_node" : "yhL7XXy-SKu_WAM-C33dzA",
        "blocks" : {},
        "nodes" : {},
        "routing_table" : {
            "indices" : {
                "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20" : {
                    "shards" : {
                        "3" : [{
                                "state" : "STARTED",
                                "primary" : true,
                                "node" : "yhL7XXy-SKu_WAM-C33dzA",
                                "relocating_node" : null,
                                "shard" : 3,
                                "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                                "version" : 22,
                                "allocation_id" : {
                                    "id" : "x_Iq88hmTqiasrjW09hVuw"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "state" : "STARTED",
                                "primary" : false,
                                "node" : "1a8dgBscTUS3c7Pv4mN9CQ",
                                "relocating_node" : null,
                                "shard" : 3,
                                "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                                "version" : 22,
                                "allocation_id" : {
                                    "id" : "DF-EUEy_SpeUElnZI6cgsQ"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "4" : [{
                                "state" : "INITIALIZING",
                                "primary" : true,
                                "node" : "1a8dgBscTUS3c7Pv4mN9CQ",
                                "relocating_node" : null,
                                "shard" : 4,
                                "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                                "version" : 1,
                                "allocation_id" : {
                                    "id" : "1tw7C7YPQsWwm_O-8mYHRg"
                                },
                                "unassigned_info" : {
                                    "reason" : "INDEX_CREATED",
                                    "at" : "2016-07-26T14:20:15.395Z",
                                    "details" : "force allocation from previous reason CLUSTER_RECOVERED, null"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
                                "primary" : false,
                                "node" : null,
                                "relocating_node" : null,
                                "shard" : 4,
                                "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                                "version" : 1,
                                "unassigned_info" : {
                                    "reason" : "CLUSTER_RECOVERED",
                                    "at" : "2016-07-26T11:24:11.868Z"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "2" : [{
                                "state" : "STARTED",
                                "primary" : false,
                                "node" : "rlRQ2u0XQRqxWld-wSrOug",
                                "relocating_node" : null,
                                "shard" : 2,
                                "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                                "version" : 22,
                                "allocation_id" : {
                                    "id" : "eQ-_vWNbRp27So0iGSitmA"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "state" : "STARTED",
                                "primary" : true,
                                "node" : "yhL7XXy-SKu_WAM-C33dzA",
                                "relocating_node" : null,
                                "shard" : 2,
                                "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                                "version" : 22,
                                "allocation_id" : {
                                    "id" : "O1PU1_NVS8-uB2yBrG76MA"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "1" : [{
                                "state" : "STARTED",
                                "primary" : false,
                                "node" : "rlRQ2u0XQRqxWld-wSrOug",
                                "relocating_node" : null,
                                "shard" : 1,
                                "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                                "version" : 24,
                                "allocation_id" : {
                                    "id" : "ZmxtOvorRVmndR15OJMkMA"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "state" : "STARTED",
                                "primary" : true,
                                "node" : "yhL7XXy-SKu_WAM-C33dzA",
                                "relocating_node" : null,
                                "shard" : 1,
                                "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                                "version" : 24,
                                "allocation_id" : {
                                    "id" : "ZNgzePThQxS-iqhRSXzZCw"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "0" : [{
                                "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
                                "primary" : true,
                                "node" : null,
                                "relocating_node" : null,
                                "shard" : 0,
                                "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                                "version" : 0,
                                "unassigned_info" : {
                                    "reason" : "CLUSTER_RECOVERED",
                                    "at" : "2016-07-26T11:24:11.868Z"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
                                "primary" : false,
                                "node" : null,
                                "relocating_node" : null,
                                "shard" : 0,
                                "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                                "version" : 0,
                                "unassigned_info" : {
                                    "reason" : "CLUSTER_RECOVERED",
                                    "at" : "2016-07-26T11:24:11.868Z"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }

            },
            "routing_nodes" : {
                "unassigned" : [{
                        "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
                        "primary" : false,
                        "node" : null,
                        "relocating_node" : null,
                        "shard" : 4,
                        "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                        "version" : 1,
                        "unassigned_info" : {
                            "reason" : "CLUSTER_RECOVERED",
                            "at" : "2016-07-26T11:24:11.868Z"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
                        "primary" : true,
                        "node" : null,
                        "relocating_node" : null,
                        "shard" : 0,
                        "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                        "version" : 0,
                        "unassigned_info" : {
                            "reason" : "CLUSTER_RECOVERED",
                            "at" : "2016-07-26T11:24:11.868Z"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "state" : "UNASSIGNED",
                        "primary" : false,
                        "node" : null,
                        "relocating_node" : null,
                        "shard" : 0,
                        "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                        "version" : 0,
                        "unassigned_info" : {
                            "reason" : "CLUSTER_RECOVERED",
                            "at" : "2016-07-26T11:24:11.868Z"
                        }
                    }

                ]
            },
            "nodes" : {
                "rlRQ2u0XQRqxWld-wSrOug" : [{
                        "state" : "STARTED",
                        "primary" : false,
                        "node" : "rlRQ2u0XQRqxWld-wSrOug",
                        "relocating_node" : null,
                        "shard" : 2,
                        "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                        "version" : 22,
                        "allocation_id" : {
                            "id" : "eQ-_vWNbRp27So0iGSitmA"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "state" : "STARTED",
                        "primary" : false,
                        "node" : "rlRQ2u0XQRqxWld-wSrOug",
                        "relocating_node" : null,
                        "shard" : 1,
                        "index" : "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
                        "version" : 24,
                        "allocation_id" : {
                            "id" : "ZmxtOvorRVmndR15OJMkMA"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you enable allocation (assuming you have it disabled before the upgrade)? `PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "transient" : {
        "cluster.routing.allocation.enable" : "all"
    }
}`

Comment: Yes, routing allocation is enabled, I've done this through Kopf. Also - worth stating - some of the shards are allocated, it's just that allocation stops and I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: Maybe it's just slow...

Comment: If you run `GET /_cluster/health?pretty` what do you see when the shards appear not to be allocated anymore?

Comment: Added above - just looks like the shards are left unassigned? I don't think it's just slow because the shards are reassigned pretty quickly up until the point that they stop - and then they just stop dead.

Comment: Ok. Do you have enough disk space?

Comment: Yes, plenty of disk space - I have 1.16TB free of 1.81

Comment: Ok. Then run `_cat/shards` and take one of the replica shards (the shard number) that is `UNASSIGNED` and the index name and update the post with it.\

Comment: Done (I think) - see above

Comment: Run the following command and provide the result: `curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute" -d'
{
  "dry_run": true, 
  "commands": [
    {
      "allocate": {
        "index": "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
        "shard": 4,
        "node": "switzerland"
      }
    }
  ]
}'`

Comment: Get this in response - {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[allocate] trying to allocate a primary shard [cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20][4], which is disabled"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"[allocate] trying to allocate a primary shard [cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20][4], which is disabled"},"status":400}

Comment: Run this one: `curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute" -d'
{
  "dry_run": true, 
  "commands": [
    {
      "allocate": {
        "index": "cs-payment-warn-2016.07.20",
        "shard": 4,
        "node": "switzerland",
        "allow_primary": true
      }
    }
  ]
}'`

Comment: I've done this - stripped back result above, but it appears to work. I have found I can force all of these shards to reroute  manually using this reroute command.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. The primaries will be allocated empty. My command above was just a simulation (`dry_run: true`)